# Laravel 5.4 api middleware caching issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am using laravel 5.4 with api middleware.

api.php

```
Route::get('/testing',function(){
echo "foo";
});
```

once I hit my url say localhost/api/testing it prints "foo" but when I change the message to  "bar" and again hit same url it prints "foo".
Seems like my change didn't had any effect and may be some caching is being done.
I tried using

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

but then too no effect.But same code when I write in web middleware it works totally fine and change is being updated .Now I am confused should I use api middleware or change my code to web middleware
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: consider using homestead. Localhost sometimes leave some cache.

Comment: But then too there would be some way to disable it

Comment: Check if you have OpCache or Varnish installed in your local setup. You're running a closure based route, which wouldn't cache unless you have some server side caching.

Comment: none of them is installed

Comment: If you're viewing it from a browser and not a REST client: have you checked to make sure it's not your browser caching the response?

Answer (score 2):

Just clear all cache from following artisan command:-

```
php artisan optimize

php artisan route:clear

php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan view:clear
```

Comment: open in incognito in chrome or as a private tab in firefix

Answer (score 0):

Use Return 'foo' instead of echo 'foo'

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that.